# Regex to match only till first occurence of class match

Tags: regex, apex-code

I'm looking to construct a regex which will help me identify the first occurrence of a match.

My current regex is `"(.*)[Cc][Aa][Ss][Ee][^a-zA-Z\\d]*(\\d\\d*)[^a-zA-Z\\d]*(.*)"`

What I am trying to do is to find if the input string contains the word "case" (case insensitive), followed by any number of special characters, followed by a number;
I want to retrieve 3 parts of the text.
Say my input string is `"RE: FW: case:-1234: there is some description"`
Using this regex, I am able to retrieve, `"RE: FW: "`, `"1234"`, `"there is some description"`.

This is fine, but if my input string is 
`"RE: FW: case:-1234: This is in reference to case 789 reopening"`
Then my regex returns, `"RE: FW: case:-1234: This is in reference to"`, `"789"`, `"reopening"`.

What I would like to get is `"RE: FW: "`, `"1234"`, `"This is in reference to case 789 reopening"`.

I am a newbie with regex, so any help is much appreciated.

Note: I am working on a java based tool, so java compatible regex would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your regex have to match the entire string (i.e. does it use `matches`)? If not (or if you can choose to use `find` instead) simply remove the `(.*)`, because that's what pushes your match back:

```
[Cc][Aa][Ss][Ee][^a-zA-Z\\d]*(\\d\\d*)[^a-zA-Z\\d]*
```

Otherwise, make the leading repetition non-greedy;

```
(.*?)[Cc][Aa][Ss][Ee][^a-zA-Z\\d]*(\\d\\d*)[^a-zA-Z\\d]*(.*)
```

By the way, you can simplify this, using case-insensitive matching. If you cannot activate it in your tool, you can do it inline in the regex:

```
(?i)(.*?)case[^a-z\\d]*(\\d+)[^a-z\\d]*(.*)
```

Note that I also simplified the number. `+` means 1 or more occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `?`

Your regex would be

```
(?i)(.*?)case[^a-z\d]*(\d+)(.*)
```

You can toggle case insensitive match using `(?i)` in regex