# Regex: match only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've got a string with multiple ip addresses together with some random stuff. For example like this one:

```
21/Jun/2018:01:15:38 +0000    188.79.169.152    157.52.69.50    443    -    -    GET / 157.52.69.30 157.52.69.10
```

And got this regex:

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}
```

Problem is that this matches multiple times, but I don't need that. What is missing with this regex so it will only match once?

Thanks,

Comment: Elaborate on exactly what you want matched please, and how are you matching (which `re` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466927/regex-to-match-only-till-first-occurence-of-class-match/17467055?noredirect=1#17467055 Does this solve your query?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: I want to match only first ip address which in this case is 188.79.169.152 and make sure 157.52.69.50 gets ignored (188.79.169.152 and 157.52.69.50 can be any ip addresses).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` which matches a ptrn from the beginning of a string
So just by adding a `.*` to the start of your pattern, we can match everything from the beginning of the string to the first ip address

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "21/Jun/2018:01:15:38 +0000    188.79.169.152    157.52.69.50    443    -    -    GET / 157.52.69.30 157.52.69.10"
>>> 
>>> ptrn = r'.*?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})'
>>> re.match(ptrn, s).groups()[0]
'188.79.169.152'
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do this without re.match approach just using native regex ?